# How to tell a SciKit LinearRegression model that a predicted value cannot be less than Zero?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have the following code that attempts to valuate stock on non-price based features.

```
price = df.loc[:,'regularMarketPrice']
features = df.loc[:,feature_list]

# 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, price, test_size = 0.15, random_state = 1)

if len(X_train.shape) < 2:
    X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1,1)

# 
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

# 
print('Train Score:', model.score(X_train,y_train))
print('Test Score:', model.score(X_test,y_test))


# 
y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

In my df (which is very large), there is never an instance where 'regularMarketPrice' is less than 0. However, I occasionally receive a value less than 0 for some points in y_predicted.

Is there a way in Scikit to say anything less than 0 is an invalid prediction? I am hoping this makes my model more accurate.

Please comment if there is a need for further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make more prediction larger than 0, you should not use linear regression. You should consider generalized linear regression (glm), such as poisson regression.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import PoissonRegressor

price = df.loc[:,'regularMarketPrice']
features = df.loc[:,feature_list]

# 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, price, test_size = 0.15, random_state = 1)

if len(X_train.shape) < 2:
    X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1,1)

# 
model = PoissonRegressor()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

# 
print('Train Score:', model.score(X_train,y_train))
print('Test Score:', model.score(X_test,y_test))


# 
y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

All prediction is greater than or equal to 0

Comment: This solved my issue. However for anyone reading this, PossionRegressor is not available in any version of scikit below 0.23 (May 12 2020). so make sure you have Scikit up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using something other than a Gaussian response variable. Plot your y-values with a histogram. If the data are right skewed, considering modeling with a glm, gamma distribution, and log link.

Alternatively, you could set the y_predicted to the max of the model.score value and 0.